# User Class Information

Tags: java

How would you put your first name and last name together with a period(.) in the middle and assign it to a String of FullName.

```
FullName = +FirstName '.'+ LastName;
```

It has got a big red 'X' next to the line.  The error is

```
The method FirstName() is undefined for the type Username
The method LastName() is undefined for the type Username
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String
Syntax error on token ""."", delete this token.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right lines, but your syntax is a little off.

```
 String fullName = firstName + "." + lastName;
```

***NOTE***: I've used the proper naming conventions, which can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

This works because you declare a new `String`, `fullName`. You then assign it the value of `firstName`, then a `"."`, then the value of `lastName`. This code assumes that `firstName` and `lastName` has already been declared previously.

**If you wanted to be more efficient..**

Then you can use a class called a `StringBuilder`. This is because concatenating `String` objects in Java is considered bad practise and highly inefficient, and `StringBuilder` offers a nicer solution to it. Sample code would be as follows.

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

 builder.append(firstName);
 builder.append(".");
 builder.append(lastName);

 String fullName = builder.toString();
```

**Edit**: Here's a link to the working code: http://ideone.com/KIIOgo

Comment: I actually did that but it is only giving me the two names together.  I was trying to put a period in the middle.

Comment: If you use the first code sample I've given you, the output will have the period in the middle, for sure.

Comment: No problem, if this answer helped you please mark it as correct when you can.